# Does Free license projects need to worry about patents?

Tags: patent-infringement, licensing

I want to create a new OS which runs on a Micro-controller (like Raspberry pi pico). Only I must control every aspect of this project and I don't allow any contributor.

I have plan to publish it with Free license (anyone can implement it, but they must put my project's information, and link to my project), and in return, I would ask for donation to keep me working on that project.

---

In my project, I have to work with the data transfer protocols like USB, UART, SWD, etc.

Should I worry about the patents and licensing of these tecnologies? Should I have to take anyone's permission to implement any one of these?

Answer (score 2):

Just because you are implementing it yourself and giving it away doesn’t prevent patent infringement.

Copyright violations require copying the original work but a patent is infringed by making or using something that fulfills the criteria stated in a claim in an issued patent that is still in force, whether or not it is intentional.

The probability of getting in trouble may not be high since you are not making money on it especially if you do not have deep pockets to be worth going after.